# getting a return value from a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have such a matlab function:

```
function j = globalfun(a, xr, x)

        gv_0 = 0;
        gv_1 = 0;

        counter1_0 = 0;
        counter1_1 = 0;
        counter2_0 = 0;
        counter2_1 = 0;
        counter3_0 = 0;
        counter3_1 = 0;
        counter4_0 = 0;
        counter4_1 = 0;
        ............................................
        ............................................
        score = gv_0/gv_1;
end
```

I haven't written all the function codes, because it is not needed.

The question is, I need to get "score" value from another script I'm using.

How can I manage the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: What is a score value? Or if you want to return the value "score" from the function?

Comment: score is a value calculated inside of the algorithm.

Comment: If you need `score` somewhere else, return it: `function [j,score] = globalfun(a, xr, x)`

Comment: So, do you want to return the value "score" from your function?

Comment: yes, exactly. When I run the code, I get the error "too many input arguments."

Comment: Daniel, I need the score like this: scoref1 = globalfun(1, xr, x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you copy-pasted the function syntax from somewhere and that you don't need to return `j`. Define this function in `globalfun.m`

```
function score = globalfun(a, xr, x)
    ...
    score = gv_0/gv_1;
end
```

The value of score is assigned within `globalfun` and will be set as return value. Then call it from a script or another function

```
myscore = globalfun(a, xr, x)
```

If you need multiple return values, use square brackets

```
function [i,j,score] = globalfun(a, xr, x)
    ...
    i = ...
    j = ...
    score = gv_0/gv_1;
end
```